# php contact form to mail

Tags: php, json, email

hi kindly i need help here.  Am trying to submit information in contact form but its returning a parse error. The submit form is supposed to send details to my email address once the user clicks post homework button. Here is the code:

```
<?php 
$send_email_to = "email@example.com";

function send_email($name,$email,$phone,$subject,$message)
{
  global $send_email_to;  
  if($message=='message')$message='';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: ".$email. "\r\n";
  $message = "<strong>Email = </strong>".$email."<br>";  
  $message .= "<strong>Name = </strong>".$name."<br>";     
  $message .= "<strong>Phone = </strong>".$phone."<br>";     
  $message .= "<strong>Message = </strong>".$message."<br>";
  @mail($send_email_to, $subject, $message,$headers);
  return true;
}

function validate($name,$email,$phone,$message,$subject)
{
  $return_array = array();
  $return_array['success'] = '1';
  $return_array['name_msg'] = '';  
  $return_array['email_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['phone_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['message_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['subject_msg'] = '';

 if($email == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['email_msg'] = 'email is required';
  }
  else
  {
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['email_msg'] = 'Enter valid email.';  
    }
  }

  if($name == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['name_msg'] = 'Name is required';
  }
  else
  {
     $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
     $return_array['name_msg'] = 'Enter valid Name.';
    }
  }

  if($phone == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['phone_msg'] = 'Phone is required';
  }
  else
  {
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
     if (!preg_match($string_exp, $phone)) {
       $return_array['success'] = '0';
     $return_array['phone_msg'] = 'Enter valid Phone.';
    }
  }

  if($subject == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['subject_msg'] = 'Subject is required';
  }

  if($message == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['message_msg'] = 'Message is required';
  }
  else
  {
    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['message_msg'] = 'Enter valid Message.';
    }
  }  

  return $return_array;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$return_array = validate($name,$email,$phone,$message,$subject);
if($return_array['success'] == '1')
{
  send_email($fname,$email,$phone,$subject,$message);
}

header('Content-type: text/json');
echo json_encode($return_array);
die();

?>
```

Comment: It's better to provide your error.

Comment: I would advise not being overly strict about email address validation.  For example, email addresses are allowed to contain the `+` character, but it would fail in your code.  Also, domains like `.co.jp` would fail as well. In general if the address has exactly one `@` and at least one `.` after the at-sign, it is probably OK for the purpose of your code.

Comment: have you specified your email address

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me for many years on many servers.
What comes after -fmailer@ does not matter. ps.com is not valid

```
  $mailheaders = "From:  your@email_address.com <> \n";
  $mailheaders .= "Reply-To: your@email_address.com \n\n";
  if (mail($to,$subject, $message, $mailheaders, "-fmailer@ps.com")){
    success
  }
  else{
    fail
  }
```

If there is a problem with delivery you may or may not receive a a message it was undeliverable. Email servers often will not reply to an invalid user.

As far as validation just include a link in you email message ask them to click it to validate they received it. Add a validated field to your contact table record that the email is validated and when validated no longer include the validation message.